# ValueError while saving ndarray

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Working on Windows XP, I have a numpy ndarray of shape `(300, 224, 256)`, so containing something like 17 million items. It contains integer-values.
When I try to save this array using `numpy.save` everything works fine. However, I need to process the data and in this flow convert it to float32. And if I do so, I cannot save the array anymore:

```
>>>myarray.dtype
dtype('int16')

>>>np.save('myfile.npy', myarray)

>>>np.save('myfile.npy', myarray.astype(np.float32))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-1c817b31fd22> in <module>()
----> 1 np.save('myfile', myarray.astype(p.float32))

C:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in save(file, arr)
    409     try:
    410         arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
--> 411         format.write_array(fid, arr)
    412     finally:
    413         if own_fid:

C:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.pyc in write_array(fp, array, version)
    407     else:
    408         if isfileobj(fp):
--> 409             array.tofile(fp)
    410         else:
    411             # XXX: We could probably chunk this using something like

ValueError: 17203200 requested and 1004 written
```

My first guess was, that the network drive I am trying to save to ran out of space. But that does not seem to be the case. Can anyone point me towards why this is happening, and why only when using float32, and how I might be able to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I [googled](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2312) around [a bit](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg20179.html) and it seems that it's either that you ran out of hard drive space or there was an overflow error.  Have you tried saving it off to your local hard drive?  Have you tried an array that has size `(300, 224, 255)`?  Try out several tweaks to see if you get different results.

Comment: As I said, an Array of type int16 with the same shape can be saved in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, but when you convert to `float32`, you increase the amount of space it takes up.  `float32` takes up more room than `int16`.

Comment: So, when I save the same array in `float32` to my local drive, it works and takes up approximately 66MB. The network drive should have about 23GB of free space.
This still doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't know then.  The mail chain I linked you to was a bit over my head, admittedly, but the open bug on github makes it look like you aren't the only one with this problem.  Bump the bug on github by commenting on it with your setup.

Comment: Does not solve the problem obviously, but nevertheless, thank you for the effort

Comment: Thanks bheklilr. I was getting this error on Linux with `numpy.savez_compressed()` and it turned out /tmp is full (looks like numpy saves the file to /tmp before compressing it)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little old, but there's something everyone seems to have overlooked. Even though your command is "np.save('myfile.npy', myarray.astype(np.float32))", the error message reports the command as "np.save('myfile', myarray.astype(p.float32))"

Since p.float32 isn't a dtype, is it possible that this was just caused by a typo?